# What's the name of long bar with rounded corners and rounded image inside of it?

Tags: android, material-design

What's the name of long bar with rounded corners and rounded image on bar side?

I can not recall that name. Previously I saw it in one of the Google's app. I tried to find it on the internet by using word "strip" but I got only inappropriate photos.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is named as `Chip` by Material Design. See more [here, on Chips - Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html)

Comment: this can also have multiple other ways to create that, right? some examples, TextView & css styles, Button & css styles, layout w& css, the css for rounding the corners.

Comment: Lol. But named as `Chip` by Google team from Material Design. It is all